# let $V$ be a unitary finite space , and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation , there exists a natural $n$ such that $T^n=I$, is $T=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a unitary finite space , and let $T: V \to V$ be a non negative linear transformation , there exists a natural $n$ such that $T^n=I$, is $T=I$?

---

My try:

First we are given that $V$ is finite, $T:V \to V$ is non negative therefore a transformation is non negative if it is Hermitian adjoint $(T= \bar T)$ to itself and for every $v \in V$ we get $(T(v) , v) \geq 0$

let $v \in V$

I could not find a translation to this theorem but in the book it is called "the unitary diagonal theorem" (a linear transformation in a unitary finite space is a diagonalizable iff it is normal this is a direct translation) according to the book from that we get that there is an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ for $V$ which are the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues of $T$ , $T(v_i) = \lambda_i v_i$ $(i=1,...n)$ and according to inner product and the definition of non negative transformation we get $(T(v),v)=(\lambda v,v)=\lambda ||v||^2 \geq 0$ we know that $v$ is an eigenvector so it is non-zero and by the definition above $((T(v) , v) \geq 0)$ we get that $||v||^2 >0$ so $\lambda \geq 0$

EDIT 1 - Given $T^2=I$ we get $\lambda^nv=I(v)=v$ according to that $\lambda^n v = v $ $\iff$ $\lambda^n=1$ $\iff$ $\lambda =1$ and $T(v_i)= \lambda_u v_i$ and since $\lambda=1$ we got $T(v_i)=v_i=I(v_i)$

I got stuck here and couldn't find how to use the given information..

Thanks for any tips and help!

and sorry if some of the translations are incorrect hope it is understandable

Comment: You are only missing the final step: Apply $T^n$ to each $v_i$.
What can you find about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: Some remarks: 1) from the question it does not follow that dim $V = n$, the dimension of $V$ and the natural $n$ such that $T^n = I$ are not necessarily the same; 2) write $T(v_i) = \lambda_i v_i$, since you can have different eigenvalues.